# what does 'testConnectionOnCheckin' in c3p0 mean?

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I have been trying to go through the c3p0 documentation but not able to understand 'testConnectionOnCheckin' property.

Docs says - "Connections are tested before they are included in pool".

Does this property apply to only new connections that c3p0 creates are tested before they are included in pool? What is point of checking new connections? Wouldn't they generally be valid?

Also couple of days my application logs were showing following:

```
[managed:2 unused:2 excluded:1]
```

And my application was throwing exception for one particular connection which I assume is 'excluded' one. Is 'excluded' connection counted in pool and can c3p0 hand it over to application without checking validity? If not, then would setting 'testConnectionOnCheckin' test this excluded connection for validity before it is used by my application?

I apologize for too many questions but it's just that I am confused.

Thanks
Jitendra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

testConnectionOnCheckin tests Connections after they are checked-in by clients [ie via Connection.close()], but before they are reintegrated into the Connection pool. I'm not sure what documentation you are looking at, but see

http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#testConnectionOnCheckin

http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

I generally recommend testing Connections with a combination of idleConnectionTestPeriod and testConnectionsOnCheckIn (and a fast preferredTestQuery).

An "excluded" Connection is a Connection currently in use by a client, but which c3p0 has noticed is faulty. c3p0 marks these Connections to be destroyed rather than reintegrated into the pool when they are checked-in by the client.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Steve. In out application, we code with sessionFactory, getCurrentTransaction, start transaction, do operation and commit transaction. Is connection.close called when we commit the transaction?

Comment: i'm not so strong on hibernate, so take this with a grain of salt. but i think it's a hibernate Session that maps to a Connection. so from a Connection pooling perspective, the safest bet is to close your Sessions. however, under some settings, hibernate automatically maps the lifecycle of "physical" Sessions to transactions, while maintaining a longer-running logical "currentSession". this should be fine, as physical Connections should endure only within transactions. see https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions to verify your Session management strategy.